# Query the nearest range

Tags: algorithm, nearest-neighbor, kdtree

I have two sets, A and B. The sets are made of N dimension points and ordered (N<10). I need find the nearest part of B to A. Let's say the nearest part is B1. The count of points in B1 should be same as A, and the sum of distances of all points in B1 to A should be minimum.

I have checked k-d tree. It only helps to find nearest point in a set. So is there an algorithm to find the nearest range in a fast way?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you simply require a *n nearest neighbours search* algorithm here, which is a simple extension of the nearest neighbour algorithm. Run this for each point in set A and minimise the sum total.

The algorithm is mentioned in [this article](http://www.autonlab.org/autonweb/14665/version/2/part/5/data/moore-tutorial.pdf?branch=main&language=en) ("An intoductory tutorial on kd-trees"). The extension to more than one nearest neighbour is only mentioned briefly, but it should be quite clearly. It is the article from which I successfully implemented the modified algorithm.

A reference implementation in C# can be accessed here, which is commented and contains relevant unit tests. It should be easy to adapt to the imperative language of your choice.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But the problem is the returned points should be continuous in sets. If the first point of B1 is b6, the next points should be b7,b8,b9...  The results of KNN returns are not continuous.

Comment: Continuous? What do you mean? You're evidently not using the mathematical definition of the term, which relates to epsilon-delta infinitesimals.

Comment: For example, A = {a1,a2,a3..am} and B = {b1,b2,b3....,bn}. B1 is the nearest range to A and it starts from b3. Then the B1 should be {b3,b4,b5..b3+m}. The distances between B1 and A are b3->a1, b4->a2, b5->a3...am->b3+m.